# Setting up OpenGL in MSVC 2012

Tags: opengl

I am trying very hard to install OpenGL on Visual Studio 2012, but even with GLUT, it doesn't work.

I read this other question, but it didn't work too:
[How do you install GLUT and OpenGL in Visual Studio 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12171317/how-do-you-install-glut-and-opengl-in-visual-studio-2012)

So basically, I am left with no choice, but to ask on how am I about to link those libraries? Explain each step and bear in mind that I am using x64 Windows 7.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. "it doesn't work" is not useful information to us. If you would post a detailed description of what you did, how it didn't work, and how you expected it to work, we would be more likely to be able to help you.

Comment: I tried to add the files into VC11 lib, includes and the dll to their place, just like I always do with other libraries like Allegro 5, but it turns out it doesn't work. I tried to link from the project folder, still it won't. The files where to put them, suggested below, don't exist. (SysWOW64 is, but Windows SDK doesn't exist at all)

Answer (score 1):

1. Copy the `glut32.dll`, `glut.dll` and paste them in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` folder.
2. Copy `glut.h` file and paste it in `C:Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A` (maybe it `9.0A`, not `7.0A`)`\Include\gl` folder. If there is no `gl` folder, create a new one.
3. Copy `glut32.lib`, `glut.lib` and paste them in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Lib` folder.

Now you can create visual c++ console application project and include glut.h header file then you can write code for GLUT project.

```
#pragma comment(lib, "opengl32.lib") 
#pragma comment(lib, "glu32.lib") 
#pragma comment(lib, "glaux.lib") 
#include <gl/GL.h> 
#include <gl/GLU.h> 
#include <gl/GLAUX.H>
#include <gl/GLUT.H>
```

Comment: There is no Microsoft SDKs folder and neither glut.dll. Your answer doesn't work. I don't know why I got -1 for asking and you got +1 for not answering the right answer?