# What version of OpenGL comes with Visual Studio 2012 Express?

Tags: opengl, visual-studio-2012

[How do you install GLUT and OpenGL in Visual Studio 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12171317/how-do-you-install-glut-and-opengl-in-visual-studio-2012) explains that the OpenGL headers and libraries come with VS2012. How do I determine which versions of the OpenGL standard are supported by these libraries? I recently purchased [the 8th Edition of the OpenGL redbook](http://opengl-redbook.com/) which is based on OpenGL 4.3. Will I be able to run and compile these examples with VS2012 Express?

Answer (score 6):

OpenGL *implementation* is brought to you by your graphics card driver, not by your OS (except really old stuff). When you install the GPU driver, appropriate library (such as `nvogl32.dll` on my PC with NVidia card) is placed in your `System32/SysWOW64` folder.

To actually acess the functions in the driver, you need a loader library (such as GLload or GLEW) that will ask the driver dll nicely where do the functions reside. You can also do it manually, but it's extremely cumbersome.

Comment: Won't the dev environment determine the headers you have available? The headers determine whether you can use old-school `glBegin()` and `glEnd()` rather than shaders, right?

Comment: @MonadNewb Thing is that headers supplied by default with windows consist only of those "old-school" cruft. You can use [this header](http://www.opengl.org/registry/api/GL/glcorearb.h), but you still a loader to supply the definitions of those functions.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the opengl version in runtime via:

```
glGetString(GL_VERSION)
```

after opening a gl context. Other usefull information about this gl call [here](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetString.xml)

Comment: Except that way of getting extensions is deprecated. [Look here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17924614/752976)