# cannot open file opengl32.obj in visual studio 2012, windows 8.1

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2012, freeglut

I've been trying to include freeglut as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12171317/how-do-you-install-glut-and-opengl-in-visual-studio-2012) post, but when I try to compile a simple project, consisting on an empty main function I get the linker error

> error LNK1104: cannot open file 'opengl32.obj'
>   C:\Users\Anders\Dropbox\Special Kursus\AMoN\AMoN\LINK

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, you'll have a hard time trying to link `opengl32.obj`, because unless you're a developer at Microsoft who builds the `opengl32.dll` API interface DLL you'll never see that compilation unit. What you need to link instead is the symbol reference table library `opengl32.lib` (note the suffixing `.lib`).

Comment: Thanks, this made me double check the additional dependencies. Forgot to add the ".lib", all I had was "opengl32"

Comment: It works too with glu32 --> **glu32.lib**. I added this to Project > Properties > Configuration Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies > Edit > Add the values in the pane (opengl32.lib and/or glu32.lib) > OK > Apply > OK.